Use firewalld to block some docker Application
i have a virtual machine (libvirt) running docker and some application on it. Some applications should not accessed from the host system but they need to be accessed from the docker host. So i tried resolving this using firewalld this is my libvirt zone:

sudo firewall-cmd --zone=libvirt --list-all
libvirt (active)
  target: ACCEPT
  ingress-priority: 0
  egress-priority: 0
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: virbr0
  sources:
  services: dhcp dhcpv6 dns ssh tftp
  ports:
  protocols: icmp ipv6-icmp
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
rule family="ipv4" port port="9090" protocol="tcp" reject
rule priority="32767" reject


firewalld service is active and running but i can still access the application via the browser. Any idears how i can solve this?
